# Dual boot with windows 10 fails to boot usb

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

I have installed on my new pc windows 10. I have a bootable usb with Ubuntu 16. When I plug it in and select to boot from usb, it warns me about `secure boot`, although it is disabled.

I have AMD ryzen 5 cpu ASUS motherboard.

The installation seemed to start on the first try, but stuck in the middle and restarted. Then it couldn't load again.

How can I set up Ubuntu with dual boot?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Under Windows OS type is there another selection like "Other". Usually Windows means UEFI Secure Boot. You still want UEFI not the old CSM/BIOS/Legacy mode. And then is there another screen with settings that say allow USB boot? Most Secure systems have USB boot set to not allow or off. On my system I had to use a boot mode that was UEFI only as even one that said UEFI or BIOS only offered BIOS boot.

Comment: I couldn't find another relevant option for usb boot... Does CSM has anything to do with it?

Comment: CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode  And on my system the UEFI settings were under the CSM settings. Seemed backwards to me, but that is where the UEFI settings were.

Comment: I have added my CSM configurations, still doesn't boot from USB, same error `secure boot`

Comment: "Another weird thing that happend is that the installation seemed to start on the first try, but stuck in the middle and restarted". So do you boot to the flash drive, see the ubuntu screen and then it restarts?

Comment: Did you disable fast boot on windows?

Comment: No I didn't, I'll try it now. And for your first question, now I don't see anything related with ubuntu, only the windows home screen.

Comment: I have disabled fast boot, but it still display error about secure boot for `launch EFI shell from usb drives`

Comment: I tried to start a chat with you, but i dont know if you received the invitation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Vitor Abella, I managed to fix it using a different format for the `usb`, as mentioned [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3369797/asus-boot-uefi-disable-secure-boot.html#r19475308).
The solution was to make the partition `GPT`, as described in the blog answer.

Comment: The last hope worked. Please, copy what is in your link here and adapt to Ubuntu, because it is for Windows. Then if the link breaks, the content will remain on our community. Besides that, add the things you changed in the BIOS, having your pictures as reference.