# MSI B350 PC MATE with Ryzen 5 USB ports not working

Tags: usb

I am having trouble getting the USB ports on my MSI B350 PC MATE to work in Ubuntu.  The ports work in BIOS and GRUB but when I tried to boot to a Live USB the USB keyboard turned off and then I ended up with a lot of error messaged about couldn't allocate usb_device.  If I use a live CD and a PS/2 mouse I am able to install Ubuntu, but even after running all the updates the USB devices are still not working.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: There are several postings about the B350 MB and USB boot issues, none of which seems to have an accepted answer.  You could review these posts and see if any of them helps you.  [https://askubuntu.com/questions/942786/dual-boot-with-windows-10-fails-to-boot-usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942786/dual-boot-with-windows-10-fails-to-boot-usb)  and [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106722/kubuntu-liveusb-kernel-panic-on-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106722/kubuntu-liveusb-kernel-panic-on-boot)

Comment: and [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070387/impossible-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-on-a-new-computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070387/impossible-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-on-a-new-computer) and [https://askubuntu.com/questions/950124/problems-installing-ubuntu-on-amd-mb-with-ryzen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950124/problems-installing-ubuntu-on-amd-mb-with-ryzen)